# Ошибка при создании файлов на рабочем столе

Tags: python, файлы

Программа создаёт файлы на рабочем столе.

```
import sys,os
names = ["File1","File2","File3","File4","File5"]
    for file in names:
        some = open(os.path.join("Desktop:\\",file + ".txt"),"w",encoding = "utf- 8")
        with some as f:
            f.write(write)
```

Но выходит такая ошибка:

```
some = open(os.path.join("Desktop:\\",file + ".txt"),"w",encoding = "utf- 8")


SError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Desktop:\\File1.txt'
```

Как её решить?

P.S Одна из возможных проблем , это то - что я сижу на русской windows 10 где все рабочий стол подписан как "Рабочий стол" , но если заменить этот же скрипт на рабочий стол ничего не изменится .

```
some = open(os.path.join("Рабочий стол:\\",file + ".txt"),"w",encoding = "utf- 8")
```

Comment: путь неверный. Если не существует ещё, можно задать отдельный вопрос: «как найти путь к рабочему столу на Windows 10 на Питоне 3»

Comment: @jfs Так как мне этот путь написать , у всех же windows 10 одинаковая и вроде как название рабочего стола поменять нельзя.

Comment: Я имел в виду, что если вы не нашли существующий Stack Overflow вопрос на эту тему, то задайте новый вопрос с помощью кнопки [ask] (более общий вопрос, который я выше привёл, возможно более широкому кругу людей пригодится).

Comment: @True-hacker, посмотрите [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34275945/5741205)

Comment: @MaxU: `expanduser('~/Desktop')` а это работает на русской Windows? или если пользователь специальные папки в другое место руками назначил? Я бы посмотрел на `winpaths.get_desktop()`  для начала

Comment: @jfs, там по ссылке другое решение для Windows

Comment: @MaxU: чем вообще USERPROFILE полезен по сравнению с `expanduser('~')` (которое работает и на Windows)? Как USERPROFILE решает указанные проблемы (русский язык, перенос в другие места)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неверно указаны путь к рабочему столу. Путь, отображаемый проводником не всегда отображает реальное размещение файлов. В частности, подмена реального длинного пути на псевдонимы происходит для рабочего стола, домашней папки, папок по-умолчанию для изображений, видео и т.п. Реально они расположены в пользовательском разделе (обычно это `C:\Users\имя_пользователя\имя_папки`). Настоящий путь к рабочему столу, скорее всего, что-то типа `C:\Users\имя_пользователя\Desktop`

Comment: Да,вы правы , вы отгадали правильный путь к рабочему столу))